# Extracting lines between org sections

Tags: regex, bash

I have the following bash function.  Would like to capture the comment character
from matching the beginning pattern `^[[:space:]]*(#|;|!)+[[:space:]]*Mode: org$`
whether `#`, `;`, or `!`.  But also for `//` and `@c`, so that I can remove it from
the sections selected.

```
capture ()
{
 local efile="$1"

 local begorg endorg charcl

 impl="1"
 if [ "$impl" = "1" ]; then 
   charcl='^[[:space:]]*(#|;|!)+[[:space:]]*' 
 elif [ "$impl" = "2" ]; then
   charcl='^[[:space:]]*(//|@c)[[:space:]]*' 
 fi 
 
 begorg="${charcl}"'Mode: org$'
 endorg="${charcl}"'# End of org$'
 
 awk -v ccls="$charcl" -v bego="$begorg" -v endo="$endorg" \
   '$0 ~ bego { found=1; next } 
    $0 ~ endo { found=0; } 
    found { sub(/ccls/,""); print }' "$efile"
}
```

Here is what a file could look like

```
 ## Mode: org
 #  Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
 #  options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
 #  arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
 #  prefix `-'.
 ## # End of org

 ;; Mode: org
 ;  Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
 ;  options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
 ;  arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
 ;  prefix `-'.
 ;; # End of org
 
 @c Mode: org
 @c Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
 @c options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
 @c arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
 @c prefix `-'.
 @c # End of org
```

The output should be

```
Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
prefix `-'.

Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
prefix `-'.

Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
prefix `-'.
```

Comment: `pandoc -f org -t plain file.org` might be useful to you (if you have pandoc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you want to remove the section beginning and end lines as well as the comment characters at the beginning of a line, and print the lines in the section. Since you use GNU bash, here's a suggestion with GNU sed:

```
capture ()
{
    sed -n 's/^ *\(\([#;!]\)\2*\|\/\/\|@c\) *//;# remove any comment beginning
            T                                  ;# go to next line if no comment
            /^Mode:/,/^# End/{                 ;# from section beginning to end
                /^Mode:/d                      ;# delete section beginning
                s/^# End.*//                   ;# empty section end line
                p                              ;# print section line
            }
           ' $1
}
```

Comment: The comments would only occur between `Mode: org` and `End of org`, the remaining lines will have code and also comments.

Comment: Then your example is wrong, isn't it? Where you wrote what the _output should be_, you included the lines between the comment sections - or why are those empty lines there?

Comment: The empty lines are to separate each section.  The empty lines are introduced in the output.

Comment: I changed the answer according to the clarified requirement.